# Refreshing JList not working?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jlist

I've got a `JList` inside a `JFrame` in `class A`. I then open another `JFrame` in `Class B` which `extends` Class A. Inside this class I `AddElement();` to the `JList` but the `JList` doesn't auto redraw with the new item in it. From debugging I can tell for sure that the item gets added to the model but the `JList` isn't redrawing. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

edit: I'm using the default model.

Comment: Are you using a custom model? Do you fire the correct event?
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireIntervalAdded%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: If you are using default model than compare your work with this example this does it perfectly.http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/javaxswing/atomiccontrols/jlist/jlistrefresh.html

Comment: Problem is my JFrame which add's is in another class. When I call model.addElement(item); I get a null pointer. model is equal to null. why?

Comment: can you post code . and also the line no where you get NPE

Comment: @"I then open another JFrame in Class B which extends Class A." There are 2 frames and 2 Jlists in 2 separate classes?

Comment: It was just one JList, I solved is by making it static (doh!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just one JList, I solved is by making it static (doh!)

Comment: If you need static to access the JList you most probably have some issues with your design. If you post the relevant code people might point you to better solutions...